# Why is a loop going once around $S^1$ a generator of its fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Referencing Munkres' Topology - in many proofs the authors use the fact that a loop going once around a circle ($S^{1}$) generates that circle's fundamental group. Why is this so?

Comment: Are you familiar with covering spaces and lifting?

Comment: I did read the proof of why the fundamental group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ using those concepts... should I review that more carefully for this answer?

Comment: Yes, as the loop going around $S^1$ once corresponds to $1$ in $\mathbb Z$, and it should be clear that $1$ generates $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: ok i see. thanks!